# Python using objects from one class in another class

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning the basics of classes and object based programming (in python 2.7?). I am trying to be able to have access to the objects in the points class in my circle class but i am getting a no attribute error.

```
class Point:
  #constructor
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

class Circle:
  def __init__(self,center,radius):
    self.center.x = center.x
    self.center.y = center.y
    self.radius = radius

p1 = Point(2,3)
#print p1
c1 = Circle(p1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to pass the values of the x and y attributes of your point object to the circle, and treat the center of the circle as a tuple (or a list):

```
class Point:
  #constructor
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

class Circle:
  def __init__(self, center, radius):
  self.center = center
  self.radius = radius

p1 = Point(2,3)
c1 = Circle((p1.x, p1.y), 2)
```

Here you reference x and y as attributes of p1. The main thing is that you have to specify what attributes you want to pass in order to build the circle. There are other ways to do what you want, but it depends on what the ultimate goal is.

EDITED:
In response to your comment, you could do this:

```
class Circle:
  def __init__(self, center_x, center_y, radius):
    self.center_x = center_x
    self.center_y = center_y
    self.radius = radius

p1 = Point(2,3)
c1 = Circle(p1.x, p1.y, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there a way this can be implemented so that I can grab the x and y values seperately, as in calling center.x to return 2 and center.y returns 3?

Comment: I just figured it out right before i saw your response. all i have to do is simply initialize self.center = center . Then i called passed c1 = Circle(p1,2) and used c1.center.x